# Not sure why I'm getting this syntax error

Tags: java, syntax

Not sure why but I'm getting a syntax error on the first curly brace, it's saying I need to add a closing brace after the first variable is declared.

```
public class DogNeeds extends PetNeeds {
    super.setAnimalType("dog"); //This method is inherited from PetNeeds superclass
    protected boolean walk;

    public DogNeeds(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }   

    boolean getWalk() {
        return walk;
    }

    void setWalk(boolean walk) {
        this.walk = walk;
    }

    public void walkDog() {
        if(walk) {
            System.out.println("Time to walk " + super.getName());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(super.getName() + " doesn't need to go out yet.");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: place the `super.setAnimalType` statement in a method

Comment: You can't have a line like `super.setAnimalType("dog")` outside a method, constructor, or initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
super.setAnimalType("dog"); //This method is inherited from PetNeeds superclass
```

must be inside a method or constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`super.setAnimalType("dog")` cannot be outside a method. You can add it to any method or to an overriding method. Example:

```
public class DogNeeds extends PetNeeds {

  protected boolean walk;

  public DogNeeds(String name) {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  void setAnimalType(String animal) {
     super.setAnimalType(animal);
  }

  boolean getWalk() {
    return walk;
  }

 void setWalk(boolean walk) {
    this.walk = walk;
 }

 public void walkDog() {
    if(walk) {
       System.out.println("Time to walk " + super.getName());
    }
    else {
       System.out.println(super.getName() + " doesn't need to go out 
       yet.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`super.setAnimalType("dog");`
When you call a method like this, it should go inside your own method. Since it is not a declaration of any kind, it should be executed somewhere in a function/method.

P.S. I actually made a similar mistake this morning, silly me.